# How to access array members in lambdas?

Tags: c++, lambda

I have this piece of code in my setup that setup some lambda functions on an array of objects for when their value changes:

```
for(int i = 0; i < kNumFreqs; i++)
{
    settings.freqs[i]->setChangeFunction([&](float newValue){
        DBG("filter" << i << ": " << newValue);
        presetDirty = true;
    });
}
```

The problem is that inside the lambda, the value of i is garbage. How do I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try capturing `i` by value like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < kNumFreqs; i++)
{
    settings.freqs[i]->setChangeFunction([i](float newValue){
        DBG("filter" << i << ": " << newValue);
        presetDirty = true;
    });
}
```

(The change happened between the `[]` of the lambda)

Comment: That worked, although I also need 'this', so it became [i, this]. Thank you.

Comment: As a general advice, it is considered good practice to always explicitly write what you want to capture.